# Как оставить постоянно работающий сервер nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Я поднимаю сервер с помощью express (node js)

Потом в консоли выполняю:

```
node app
```

И сервер работает до тех пор пока я не закрою консоль.

Как заставить сервер всегда работать? даже с закрытой консолью?

Comment: node app.js & .. первое что в голову пришло)
Мб стоит рассмотреть внесение приложения в systemctl

Comment: pm2, запуск как служба